# SVG background underneath image

Tags: css, image, svg, background

So what I'm trying to do is have an SVG overlay on an image on hover. Eventually I will animate it, but for now I'm just trying to get the overlay working. This is what I tried:

```
<div class="centering margin-on-top">
   <img id="img1" src="media/circle-1.jpg" />
   <img id="img2" src="media/circle-2.jpg" />
   <img id="img3" src="media/circle-3.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#img1:hover {
    background: url("../svg/stroke-ears.svg") no-repeat;
}
```

At first I thought it wasn't working at all. But then when I put the hover on the containing div instead and deleted the picture inside the "inspect element" window, the svg was there but hidden underneath the image.

Is there a way for me to maybe set a z-index on the image or the background?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to this:

```
#img1 {
    position: relative;
}
#img1:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url("../svg/stroke-ears.svg") no-repeat;
}
```

What you're doing is creating a pseudo-element to overlay on top of the `img`.  Your original `img` had the background applied to the background of the `img` as opposed to overlaying it.

This new solution creates an element outside the normal DOM that will treat your `img` as a container and cover the entirety of its dimensions with an element that has the original background you wanted applied.

## Update

## [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wqovrh3f/)

So, silly me, trying to treat `img`s as containing elements.  Here's the fix.

**HTML**

```
<div class="inline-container centering margin-on-top">
    <div class='img-holder'>
        <img id="img1" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div class='img-holder'>
        <img id="img2" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/FBC93D" />
    </div>
    <div class='img-holder'>
        <img id="img3" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/075883" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inline-container {
    font-size: 0;
}
.img-holder {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.img-holder:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
    background: url("http://placeskull.com/200/200") no-repeat;
}
```

You could easily swap the images to be background images on the new div, too, if you wanted to shorten up your HTML.

Comment: Nothing has happened. Yet, now when I apply the :hover selector in the inspect element window the CSS rule doesn't appear. Guessing because of the :after.

Comment: Fantastic! The overlay works great! :D Only thing is that I think with the absolute positioning it's messing with the other css on the page. The images are now sliding underneath the elements below it. Have tried adding margins, padding, etc.

Comment: Try adding `z-index: 1` to the CSS for the `div`s containing the images.